# Review reminder with autologin link

Tags: login, review

We use Aitoc Reviews Booster for generating review reminder mails. Whenever a client receives a mail it has a link to the product page in it. The client needs to login to write a review, as we have disabled anonymous reviews.

Is it possible to create/use a link in the mail that makes the client login automatically? (I'm not experienced in creating magento plugins.) If another review plugin can do this, I'm prepared to take a serious look and possibly replace Reviews Booster.

Comment: All I can say about this is "Don't do it". Having an autologin through a link is a big hole in security.

Comment: Try these guys as they can customize their module to provide you this functionality - http://www.fmeaddons.com/magento/reviews-ratings-booster.html

Answer (score 2, accepted):

<strike>This i no answer, only an explanation of marius comment, but in the comments, there is too less space.</strike> ... I think now it is not a solution and not directly an answer, but at least it is not off topic :)

Many companies do that (which is no contra argument...).

The big problem is, that if someone uses the url he is logged in, can do checkouts, change addresses, use loyalty points, etc. If the url is kept in the address bar, the customer might copy paste it.

You should be really be careful with this functionality as Marius said. The problem is. Redirecting the customer after the login, to change the url is the minimum.

A better idea might be, to limit the functionality to the review. The customer is able to write a review which is checked against a unique value (which is then invalidated). And the review is linked to the customer account.

Comment: In the end we decided to open the reviews for everybody, logged in or not. We've had spam in the past, but that is not a big problem. We review the reviews, so not serious reviews are deleted.

Answer (score 0):

I used Aitoc Reviews Booster and it didn't quite worked for me. I ended up developing my own extension to send emails for customers after their purchases. It's free and if anyone interested you can [get it here](https://magento.mdnsolutions.com/extensions/mdn-review-reminder.html).